# How do you rotate Google Maps markers in GWT?

Tags: google-maps, gwt, rotation, google-maps-markers

How do you rotate Google Maps custom image markers in GWT? I would like to add and rotate individual icons based on a bearing.

Currently, I construct the markers as a plain marker overlay, as follows:

```
Icon icon = Icon.newInstance(imageUrl);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.newInstance(icon);
Marker marker = new Marker(point, markerOptions);   
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: please provide some piece of code that how you are implemented currently. It will be more clear to attend you query.

Answer (score 0):

Use GWTCanvas to achieve it. 
API : http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/javadoc/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/graphics/client/GWTCanvas.html

Examples : http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2338